# processing android SDK managerが出てこない

Tags: android, processing

processing3.5.3にandroid modeをインストールしたところ本来でるはずのSDK managerが出てこず、スクリーンショットのような画面が表示されます。
サイトで調べてみても、SDK managerがある前提で説明が載っているだけなので対処の方法がわかりません。
わかる方、対処法を教えてください。宜しくお願い致します。[image: processingのandroidタブ]

Comment: 念の為、どのようにインストールしたかも追記していただけませんでしょうか？

Comment: このサイトにある方法にしたがって行いました。http://www2.kobe-u.ac.jp/~tnishida/course/2013/programming/android.htm

Answer (score 2):

Android Modeのバージョンにもよりますが、最新（おそらく4以降）のAndroid Modeでは、PROCESSINGの標準エディタにSDK Managerのメニューは表示されません。「本来でるはずの」と書かれていますが、参照されたサイトの情報はかなり古いもので、最新版のAndroid Modeには当てはまりません。Android Mode4以降を標準エディタで利用する場合、DEBUG用の仮想端末は自動作成（もしくはインストール時にダウンロード）されます。また該当端末のOSバージョンはOreo固定となり、変更不可です。Oreo以外のOSバージョンで試したい場合は、標準エディタではなくAndroid StudioなどでPROCESSINGのAndroid Modeを利用されることを推奨します。